# EditText loosing cursor focus inside ViewPager2

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-viewpager, focus, orientation

I have a simple `ViewPager2` composed by 2 `Fragment`

```
        fragmentsList.add(new FakeFragment());
        fragmentsList.add(new TextFragment());

        viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this, fragmentsList);
        viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
        viewPager.setOrientation(ViewPager2.ORIENTATION_VERTICAL);
        
        viewPager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(new ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
                super.onPageScrollStateChanged(state);
                Log.d(TAG, "onPageScrollStateChanged: onPageScrollState ");
            }
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
                super.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset, positionOffsetPixels);
                Log.d(TAG, "onPageScrolled: onPageScrolled ");
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                super.onPageSelected(position);
                Log.d(TAG, "onPageSelected: onPageSelected ");
            }
        });
```

Inside the TextFragment I have a basic `EditText`.

**Problem :**
When I'm clicking it the `EditText` cursor focus is instantly killed and I can observe this in my logs :

```
2020-10-27 16:34:31.202 23177-23177/com.example.mytestapp D/MainActivity: onPageScrolled: onPageScrolled 
2020-10-27 16:34:31.217 23177-23177/com.example.mytestapp D/MainActivity: onPageScrolled: onPageScrolled
```

`ViewPager2` callbacks `OnPageScrolled` & `OnPageSelected` are called on the EditText click and then remove its focus because for some reason the view pager is "scrolling" according logs.

After fews tests I found that the problem was linked to view pager orientation and transformers :

```
viewPager.setOrientation(ViewPager2.ORIENTATION_VERTICAL);
```

When I remove this line, the `EditText` is not loosing the cursor focus anymore in default orientation which is horizontal.

If I'm adding a **custom transformer** to the default orientation, I'm loosing focus again.

If someone has encountered the same problem can tell me how to solve it ?

Comment: This could be working but I don't know why: 

`viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1)`

https://github.com/android/views-widgets-samples/issues/107#issuecomment-726809766